# Data table is enabling disabled columns on click of any header columns

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have Data table with 26 columns and some of them I have disabled sorting by adding "orderable" :false. I have this data tables at 3 different places in my application. It works at one place and other two places, when I click on header to sort, all the columns including disabled columns are enabled with sorting and  sorted as well. I'm not sure why this is happening. Can any please help?

Comment: We can only help if you provide a code example where the behaviour is reproduceable. You can show your code and perhaps create a fiddle, here is a starting point http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1000/

Comment: I couldn't post the code snippet. But it is a simple var table = $('#example').DataTable(); I couldn't understand why it work from a Jquery Dialog box and not from a window modal (window.showModalDialog(url, "", features);) . I'm embeding a jsp into a html and js in has the required plugin js into it. Any inputs?